# Who first called the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem "the crumpled paper theorem"?

Tags: mathematics, topology

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Explanations_attributed_to_Brouwer) attributes the remark to Brouwer himself, but I am extremely skeptical. Their [citation](https://archive.is/20130113210953/http://archives.arte.tv/hebdo/archimed/19990921/ftext/sujet5.html) goes to a webpage of a ? French educational TV show, where the remark appears to be a fictionalized explanation.

I suspect the "crumpled paper" explanation was due to someone else trying to give a down-to-earth explanation of the result. It was certainly in widespread circulation by the 1970s.

Comment: I bet this name spread via the gossipnet, just as slang words or  elementary school jokes did.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I agree... but gossip has an origin, and occasionally it can be identified.